# How to use seaborn scientific notation facetgrid and catplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I force scientific notation on the axes of a `seaborn.FacetGrid` or `seaborn.catplot` again?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key is here:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="x", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
```

#### To use the specified format of scientific notation:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randn(500),
                   "y": np.random.randn(500)*200})

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

g = sns.catplot( data=a)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### To use the default scientific notation:

Seaborn will use scientific notation automatically if your number is large (note the value of `y`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randn(500),
                   "y": np.random.randn(500)*1000000000})

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

g = sns.catplot( data=a)
# plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.show()
```

#### To avoid using scientific notation

Just use

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randn(500),
                   "y": np.random.randn(500)*200})

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

g = sns.catplot( data=a)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.show()
```

[image]